# Finding Constant C in ODE with Initial Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At some point we get:
$$te^ty=te^t-e^t+C$$

Given the initial condition:
$$y\log 2=1$$

How do we get $C$ from here?

The lecture note writes:
$$2\log 2 - 2 + C = 2\log 2$$
which I do not understand...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the initial conditon is:
$$y(\log 2)=1$$
This means that $$t= \log 2  \implies e^t=2$$

Then you have:
$$te^ty=te^t-e^t+C$$
$$\log 2\times  2 \times 1 =\log 2\times  2-2+C$$
$$2\log 2 =2\log 2-2+C$$
$$C=2$$

Comment: oh my thanks so much for the clarification, it seems like the prof didn't write the bracket for log2, and I just assumed that ylog2 be the product of y and log 2

Comment: You're welcome Yeah  Your teacher forgot the parenthesis for the initial condition and here $\log$ is for $\ln$  @RayRedoran